# I don't understand why I keep getting this error when I properly passed the props from child component to parent component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

This is the child component, then I pass "props.onSaveMemberData(memberData)" to NewMember.js

[image: Member.js]

[image: Return in Member.js]

NewMember.js

```
import React from "react";
import Member from "./Member";

const NewMember = (props) => {
    const saveMemberDataHandler = (enteredMemberData) => {
        const memberData = {
            ...enteredMemberData,
            id: Math.random().toString()
        }
        props.onAddMember(memberData) //Forward this to another parent component
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Member onSaveMemberData={saveMemberDataHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewMember
```

Then the parent component App.js

[image: App.js]

The error: Uncaught TypeError: props.onSaveMemberData is not a function

Comment: Everything seems fine to me, try to add console.log(props) in your child component and see whats coming in the output

Comment: I see, thank you let me check

Comment: Have you figured out what the problem was? if not then can you post your output ?

Comment: Not yet, still checking it @MridulGupta

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the child component rendered from `<NewMember>` component? Because it could be that you are using the one from here:

```
<Member people={members} />
```

If so then it does not have the `onSaveMemberData` props hence you see the error. Try to remove that from your App.js and check again.